# Android : Hide app content in multitasking view

Tags: android, multitasking, privacy

Anyone knows how to hide the content of your app when the user goes in the Current Apps Manager?
Like this is link is explaining for ios : http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-control-the-preview-screenshot-in-the-ios-multitasking-switcher/

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background/9822607?s=3|0.4276#9822607 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533186/replace-image-from-recent-app-menu/10533297?s=6|0.2426#10533297 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984083/show-black-preview-screen-in-task-manager-on-ics/12640403?s=7|0.2117#12640403 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284778/need-to-hide-content-of-program-from-android-overview-screen/27306602?s=9|0.1814#27306602

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare it worked with the secure flag!

Answer (score 6):

Somehow this did not work for me.. even though I read it was supposed to.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

However, using this in your activity will do the trick:

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Thanks for your answers CommonWare & NavjotSingh

Comment: Thanks that line do the job

Comment: The issue with this is it also disable taking screenshots on the device. Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

In android manifest file, in activity tag, use this

```
 android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: It will be remove entire app from multitasking view!